# How to interpret apksigner output?

Tags: android-security, apksigner

I've downloaded APK from the Internet and wanted to check it's integrity and credibility. I used `apksigner` but I don't know how interpret output result - is it safe or not? [Official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner#examples-verify) doesn't cover this subject.

Console output:

```
$ ./apksigner verify -v -Werr --print-certs --min-sdk-version 28  ~/Downloads/com...apkmirror.com.apk
Verifies
Verified using v1 scheme (JAR signing): false
Verified using v2 scheme (APK Signature Scheme v2): false
Number of signers: 1
Signer #1 certificate DN: CN=gearhead, OU=Android, O=Google Inc., L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US
Signer #1 certificate SHA-256 digest: fdb00c43dbde8b51cb312aa81d3b5fa17713adb94b28f598d77f8eb89daceedf
Signer #1 certificate SHA-1 digest: 9ca91f9e704d630ef67a23f52bf1577a92b9ca5d
Signer #1 certificate MD5 digest: eeb557fc154afc0d8eec621bdc7ea950
Signer #1 key algorithm: RSA
Signer #1 key size (bits): 2048
Signer #1 public key SHA-256 digest: 1b6110e69b38474bc06d6cba9578489b208b969f6ccf95206db9eac689063f2d
Signer #1 public key SHA-1 digest: 844d9df046e665c5630312da1a541be3e09e1afc
Signer #1 public key MD5 digest: 6f0062bb932de2a7303f506dd3412847
```

Comment: The result is indeed quite surprising. Because it says it verifies, is expect at least v1 or V2 signing to be verified as well, which is not the case here. Do you get a different output if you remove the --min-sdk-version flag?

Comment: @Pierre Yes, then I have a message "DOES NOT VERIFY
ERROR: APK Signature Scheme v2 signer #1: Malformed additional attribute #1"

Comment: Looks like a bug with the --min-sdk-version flag of apksig then. The signature does not verify so it seems that this APK has been modified after signing (or not signed correctly).

Comment: Update: it's actually a bug in apksig that has issues verifying APK that are signed with a more recent version of apksig. Try to find a more recent version of apksig if possible. If that still doesn't work, you may have to wait for the next release. It seems that this APK actually is signed correctly with APK signing V3, but the result isn't correctly displayed when you set the --min-sdk-version flag (another bug that should be fixed in a more recent version of apksig).